# Translating a single object opengl

Tags: c, opengl

I am writing code to draw the figure
[image: Correct output]

but my code gives

[image: My output]

as you can see the middle circle is missing.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>

float width, height, r = 0.3, change = 0;

void draw(float tx, float ty)
{
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for(int i = 1; i <= 1200; i++)
    {
        float x1, y1, theta;

        theta = (2 * 3.14159 * i) / 1200;
        x1 = r * cosf(theta) * height / width;
        y1 = r * sinf(theta);

        glVertex3f(x1 , y1 ,0);
    }

    glEnd();
    glTranslatef(tx, ty, 0);
}

void display()
{
    float p[6][2];
    int j = 0;

    if (change == 0)
        change = 1;
    else if (change == 1)
        change = 0;

    width =  glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH);
    height =  glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT) ;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);

    for(int i = 1; i <= 1200; i++)
    {
         float theta, x1, y1;

         theta = (2 * 3.14159 * i) / 1200;
         x1 = r * cosf(theta) * height / width;
         y1 = r * sinf(theta);

         glVertex3f(x1, y1, 0);

    if (i == 100 | i == 300 | i == 500 | i == 700 | i == 900 | i == 1100)
    {
        if(change == 0){
            p[j][0] = x1;                       
            p[j][1] = y1;
            j++;
        }
    }       

  }
  glEnd();

    for(int i=0;i<6 && change == 0;i++){
        draw(p[i][0],p[i][1]);
    }   
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(700,500);
    glutCreateWindow("circles");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Issue is when i translate first circle in draw function the center circle drawn is also translated to that point which is merged with other circle.My doubt is how to translate only one circle not the center one i tried translating by using push and pop matrix but it doesn't work.
Thank you.

Comment: Your code only draws 6 circles anyway. The function `draw` is only called from the loop `for(int i=0;i<6 && change == 0;i++) { draw(p[i][0],p[i][1]); }`

Comment: @WeatherVane my apologies, I'm experiencing browser problems

Comment: draw function draws 6 circles + 1 in display(center circle) = 7

Comment: Oh, sorry... but what was wrong with the code that *did* draw 7 circles?

Comment: That was fine but i want to know why the wrong code is translating center circle also

Comment: Perhaps you should comment-out calls `draw` and investigate where the `display` circle is being placed, and why.

Comment: i did it and got to know that the center circle is also getting translated for the first translate in draw and remains there which is merged with first circle drawn and appears as a single circle

Comment: I am mystified why you don't use `draw` with no translation for the centre circle.

Comment: That was how correct code works but i want to to know my error in the code or say learn to translate a single object in the scene.

Answer (score 1):

`glTranslatef()` changes the current matrix by appending a translation. So your translations will just accumulate. And since you do not have a transform between the first two circles, they will appear at the same positions. Your program basically does the following:

```
Draw Circle
draw()
  Draw Circle
  Move up, right (p[0])
draw()
  Draw Circle
  Move up (p[1])
draw()
  Draw Circle
  Move up left (p[2])
...
```

If you want absolute positioning, you have to reset the transform in between. This can either be done with `glLoadIdentity()` or with the matrix stack. And be sure to draw after setting the transform.

I guess you know, but in any case a little reminder: The entire matrix stack functionality is deprecated in modern OpenGL and you will need to manage the matrices yourself. I assume, when you do this, everything gets a bit clearer. So I'm not sure if there is a good reason to try to understand the interface of the matrix stack functionalities.

If you want to place each circle at a specific location, you can do something like the following:

```
void drawCircle()
{
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for(int i = 1; i <= 1200; i++)
    {
        float x1, y1, theta;

        theta = (2 * 3.14159 * i) / 1200;
        x1 = r * cosf(theta) * height / width;
        y1 = r * sinf(theta);

        glVertex3f(x1 , y1 ,0);
    }
    glEnd();    
}

void display()
{
    // ...
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    drawCircle();

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        float angle = M_PI / 3 * i;
        float tx = r * sin(angle);
        float ty = r * cos(angle);
        glPushMatrix(); //save the current matrix
        glTranslatef(tx, ty, 0); //move to the desired location
        drawCircle();
        glPopMatrix(); //restore the old matrix
    }
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: i tried adding glLoadIdentity between first Draw Circle and draw() function but it is not working

Comment: No, you have to add a translation (or some other transform) there if you want the circles to be different.

Comment: i added a glTranslatef with (0,0,0) as coordinates still it's not working

Comment: Because this does nothing. It moves everything by zero. As I said, the transforms that you apply are not absolute. They accumulate.

Comment: i changed values to (0.1,0,0) now what happens is center circle translates by 0.1 in X and when translate for first draw() is applied it translates by that amount

Comment: And this is surprising to you? Just imagine the current transform as a marker on the screen where you will draw the next circle. Each call to `glTranslate` moves the marker by some offset (not to a specific location). `glLoadIdentity` resets the marker to the initial position.

Comment: can you please post the modified code i am not able to make it

Comment: Edited the answer.